# Does "later" ever unambiguously refer to an unspecified time in the future?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm wondering about whether the meaning of "later" always can mean "later today" or if it may sometimes clearly have the meaning of an unspecified time in the future, such as a later date.

For example, the following context: two people having a conversation (Alice and Bob) and a third person not part of the conversation (Eve). Alice asks Bob whether Eve is able to lend money to Bob. It's a very large sum of money which Bob needs to have within a month. Bob answers "Eve said it's not possible now, but perhaps later".

May "later" still reasonably interpreted as "later today" in this context or is does it clearly mean an unspecified time in the future, such as a future date?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why do you think "later" means "later today"? That specific meaning isn't in any dictionary I can see. There are uses of later in phrases such as [Later Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Later_Roman_Empire) or [later in life](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/later+in+life) which clearly don't mean part of a day.

Comment: At least in my language, the equivalent word seems to often give the impression of "later the same day" when used alone, and so I was wondering about whether the English word "later" is the same in that regard.

Comment: "Later today" is probly the most common use of the single-word _Later_. But that's a matter of context, not meaning. _Later_ means _after now_ and doesn't specify an end time. That's one reason why it's so useful in putting people off.

Comment: In your context, Eve is not going to show up with a large sum the same day. But neither is her offer much use if it's later in the year, when Bob needs it within a month.